# Do commands have to be asynchronous in CQRS?

Tags: architecture, cqrs

From what I have read, CQRS designs involve asynchronous commands where commands are put in a queue. The user assumes all is okay and the UI polls or via a timer gets some feed back if all worked or not.

How would this work if I had a UI where I am dragging folders in a tree? I could have one user deleting a folder whilst another dragging a folder to it (to make it a sub folder of it).

So from the UI I could show the drag has taken place and then from in some timer check to see if my read model has be updated (i.e. check for the parent folder of the dragged folder and if it is set correctly I know it has worked).

If the user has done a number of drag operations, I would have to keep a list of these operations in the UI and check the read store (removing any successful commands from the list).

There maybe better ways to do this.

It just seems a lot of work on the UI and more prone to error whereas if I just run a synchronous command and if all is okay, then I move onto my next operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you can use synchronous commands, it will not make the problem you're describing any less of a problem; it will only mean slightly different behavior when notifying the user.

The thing to realize about commands is that they can be refused by the domain objects.  What that might mean in this case is that the first user makes changes, and then the changes the second user makes may be rejected because they refer to an invalid state.

If you want to present the current state of the system to all users, your ui is going to have to do all of the work you're concerned about anyway; that's not at all unique to CQRS.

Comment: I see this more as striving to inform users asap whether their actions succeed or not. And so in my view it's bad from a UI usability point of view to allow users to merrily drag folders around only to "call up the server" several seconds later and find out all of these actions were refused - I think the user should be informed straight away. Same case for problems with saving data (think validation!), and most if not all other error conditions.

Comment: "Striving to inform users asap whether their actions succeed or not" is not a universal requirement that every system must fulfill.  If the current state of the application is critical to determining the actions available to the user, then asynchronous commands are probably not the best design decision, but that doesn't mean that using synchronous commands is some magic bullet that will keep the state from changing *between commands issued by a single user*.

Answer (score 3):

You can very well use synchronous commands. Asynchronous commands are not required for CQRS.